# Dynamic Button Click Event is not fired when created in a Loop ASP.Net VB

Tags: button, dynamic, event-handling, controls, updatepanel

I have the same issue, but I have declared all the controls in the `page_Init()` event. When I declare a Event Handler for a Dynamically created Button within a loop and set its Address of to x function, it does not work.

Can Someone please help.

Here is the code in my `page_Init()`:

```
Private Sub DynamicControls_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init


'Dynamically Load X no. of Updates Panels, and x no. of Controls inside UpdatePanels.

    If (Not Me.DesignMode) Then                 ' Source [Error Creating Control" in the Design View in ] Source : http://tinyurl.com/obutas2

        Dim xLoop As Integer = 5

        For i = 1 To xLoop
            Dim TempUpdatePanel As New UpdatePanel
            TempUpdatePanel.ID = "MyUpdatePanel" & i
            TempUpdatePanel.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional
            UpdatePanelContainer.Controls.Add(TempUpdatePanel)

            Dim TempPanel As New Panel
            TempPanel.ID = "MyPanel" & i
            TempPanel.Width = 500
            TempPanel.Height = 200
            TempPanel.BackColor = Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke
            TempUpdatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(TempPanel)


            For x As Integer = 1 To xLoop
                Dim TempNxt_Button As New Button
                TempNxt_Button.ID = "MyNextButton" & i
                TempNxt_Button.Text = "Next >>"
                AddHandler TempNxt_Button.Click, AddressOf Me.Nxt_btn_Click
                TempPanel.Controls.Add(TempNxt_Button)

            Next

            If TempUpdatePanel.ID = "MyUpdatePanel1" Then
                TempPanel.Style.Add("display", "block")
            Else
                TempPanel.Style.Add("display", "none")
            End If

        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Here is the code for the `Nxt_btn_Click Event`:

```
Protected Sub Nxt_btn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim xLoop1 As Integer = 5

    For i = 1 To xLoop1
        Dim sTempPanel As Panel = FindControl("MyPanel" & i)

        If (sTempPanel Is Nothing) Then
        Else
            sTempPanel.Style.Add("display", "none")
        End If

        Dim sTempPanel1 As Panel = FindControl("MyPanel" & Mid(sender.ID, Len(sender.ID)) + 1)
        If (sTempPanel1 Is Nothing) Then
        Else
            sTempPanel1.Style.Add("display", "block")
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the Fix!

The Buttons that were created in the sub loop were getting declared with common button.IDs Even though they were getting created in different UpdatePanel>Panels they had the same IDs assigned to them. All I had to do is correct this line of code

From
                TempNxt_Button.ID = "MyNextButton" & i

To

```
            TempButton.ID = "Button" & i & "_" & x
```

Also, the child loop uses x as the integer instead of i now.